# Conditional in PHP

Tags: php, conditional-statements

When I run the follow code in PHP

```
if('yes' == 0)
    echo 'a';
else
    echo 'b';
```

The output is a.
I don't understand what happen?
And can I convert the php code to C source code to have a look what real happening?

Comment: `<?php var_dump((int)'yes');` will output `int(0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a dynamically typed language, and `==` is a `loose comparison operator`, meaning it will first cast values it compares to one type, `int` for that matter, and then compare them; strings are being cast to integers by taking numericals from the left part, so `1abc` casts to `1`. By that logic `yes` cast to 0, and `0 == 0` yields `true`.